# HTML Zen Coding Counter

Tags: emmet

I have a problem of generating html element text with Zen Coding:
Zen Coding ShortCut:

```
ul>(li>p{Element-$})*10
```

Generates 10 li>p elements with Element-1 code.

Is it any way to increase counter on each iteration?

Thank you.

P.S. I am working in Visual Studio 2013, but I guess Zen Coding should be universal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio has its own, unofficial implementation of Zen Coding. So it’s a bug of VS plugin implementation.

By the way, try the following abbreviation: `ul>li*10>p{Element-$}`

Comment: Thank you, Sergey. Works perfectly and now I understand the logic of zend sequence. Spasibo :-)